# An ordinal equipotent to a natural number is equal to that number

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $\alpha, \beta$ be ordinals and $n$ be a natural number. How can one prove the following
$$ \forall \alpha (\alpha \approx n \implies \alpha = n)$$
using the fact
$$ \vert \alpha \vert \le \beta \le \alpha \implies \vert \alpha \vert = \vert \beta \vert$$

and not using the fact that $n = \vert n \vert$.

Comment: What can you use about de natural $n$?

Comment: To make it clearer it is Lemma 10.6 (2) from "Set Theory An Introduction To Independence Proofs" by Kenneth Kunen

Comment: I think that you can asume that $n$ is a cardinal, because you can prove it using (1) of that Lemma.

Comment: I need (2) to prove that $n$ is cardinal (Corollary 10.7). Assume $n$ is not cardinal then $\exists \alpha < n (\alpha \approx n)$. But this is contradiction since by (2) $\alpha \approx n \implies \alpha = n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\alpha \approx n$, then $\vert \alpha \vert = \vert n\vert $.

If $n<\alpha$, then $\vert \alpha \vert = \vert n\vert \leq n <n+1 \leq \alpha$, so, by the Lemma,  $\vert n+1 \vert = \vert \alpha \vert = \vert n \vert$, a contradiction of $n\not\approx n+1$.

If $\alpha <n$, then $\vert n \vert = \vert \alpha\vert \leq \alpha <\alpha+1 \leq n$, so $\vert \alpha +1\vert= \vert n\vert =\vert \alpha\vert$, but there is a bijection between $\alpha +1$ and $n+1$(because there is a bijection between $\alpha$ and $n$), then $\vert n+1\vert =\vert \alpha +1 \vert =\vert n\vert$, again, a contradiction of $n\not\approx n+1$.

Therefore $\alpha=n$.